# Suddently The error "user is not allowed to see this application per the developer set configuration"

Tags: android, ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, authentication

From one day to another, all our users are getting this error when trying to login into facebook from our iOS and Android app made with Unity3D.

[image: Screenshot]

However, test users and users under role section can login. We have not updated the build and we do not remember to have changed anything on the facebook app. The application is live and public for everyone and the green checkmark is filled.

I want to know if there is any way to get a deeper debug to understand where this problem occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Simulator reset all content and settings.  Previous users may still be logged in.  Worked for me.